# Unable to print calculated value in new column of input.csv using awk. Its overwriting first coumn

Tags: bash, awk

## Input File content

```
 cat input.csv 
0,1083,23,24,494,'2017-01-26','LACP050K','LACP050'
0,1526,71,86,692,'2017-01-26','LACP050L','LACP050'
0,5573651,259,315,170610,'2017-01-26','LACPT11K','LACPT11'
```

Need calculate `($1+$2)/8*1024` and paste into new 9th column of csv.

```
# cat input.csv | awk -F"," '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,($1+$2)/(8*1024)}' 
 **0.132202** 24 494 '2017-01-26' 'LACP050K' 'LACP050'
 **0.186279** 86 692 '2017-01-26' 'LACP050L' 'LACP050'
 **680.3771** 259 315 170610 '2017-01-26' 'LACPT11K' 'LACPT11'
```

In above out put, first column values replaced instead of adding new column.

Comment: Am unable to reproduce this!

Comment: Are you copy pasting lines from a Windows machine to your `input.csv`?

Comment: It can be a copy/paste issue as Inian mentioned, there is no issue with the command..

Comment: The only issue I see there is that the Input Field Separator (FS) and Output Field Separator (OFS) don’t match, i.e. your input file is separated by commas and your output file by spaces. Apart from that your code looks perfectly fine. Also you don’t need to pipe from `cat` beforehand, just pass the file as the last argument argument of `awk`.

Comment: Actually on 8th column, its taking new line character which place output into first cell of next line. Don't know its solution

Comment: It sounds like you might have a file with DOS line endings (`\r\n`) in an environment expecting Unix line endings (`\n`).

Comment: Yes..dos2unix solved this issue.....thanks

Answer (score 1):

try below steps-

```
1 > cat -v input.csv (to see non printing character)
2 > dos2unix input.csv input1.csv
2 > awk -F"," '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,($1+$2)/(8*1024)}' input1.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Vipin... Its working fine now... It was due to extra characters in csv

Answer (score 0):

no need to repeat all fields, `$0` is equivalent

```
$ awk -F, '{print $0 FS ($1+$2)/(8*1024)}' file

0,1083,23,24,494,'2017-01-26','LACP050K','LACP050',0.132202
0,1526,71,86,692,'2017-01-26','LACP050L','LACP050',0.186279
0,5573651,259,315,170610,'2017-01-26','LACPT11K','LACPT11',680.377
```

this also preserves the input field delimiter.